# Is there any way to use diag() from Test::More without planning?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm writing some tests in Perl which have a fair amount of set up. This setup all lives in a module that the test scripts `use`. I want to be able to print some diagnostics from the module, and intended to use the `diag` function from `Test::More`. Problem is, when you `use Test::More`, it writes the plan so I get

> You tried to plan twice at lib/MyTest.pm line 15.

Is there any way I can use `diag` (or is there an equivalent), or am I stuck with `print STDERR`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the following code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use Test::More;
  diag('hello');
```

Just prints

```
  # hello
```

`Test::More` won't print the plan unless you tell it to. This is done by passing args to its import:

```
  use Test::More tests => 30;
```

Or by calling plan explicitly.

```
  use Test::More;
  plan(tests => 30);
```

Comment: Yup, that works. I was doing 

    use Test::More qw(diag);

Which (along with jumping to conclusions) is what got me confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Test::More qw(no_plan)
```